# In Bootstrap btn always over-ides btn-*

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some Twitter Bootstrap buttons that have `class="btn btn-small btn-success"`

The buttons should be green, but are instead blue. In Chrome Web Inspector, the green background attributes are crossed out, as the `btn-success` seems to be over-ridden by the default `btn`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version are you using, where did you get it and do you have extra CSS ? This shouldn't be happening

Answer (score 1):

This means the blue is taking priority, this could be one of two reasons. The selector on the blue is stronger (`#header #nav #item` is "stronger" than #item alone) or the blue is done later on in the style sheet.

Trying adding !important to the end e.g. `.class { color: green !important; }` to over ride it